# Convert 2D Shape to 1D Space (Shape Classification. )

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm looking for a example of code/library using Python to convert a 2D shape to 1D space based on following steps:

1. Find the centroid of the shape.
2. By choosing the centroid as a reference origin, unwrap the outer contour counterclockwise to turn it into a distance signal that is composed of all between each boundary pixel and the centroid (like the image)

[image: Convert 2d shape to 1d space]

Thank you!

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but center of mass can be calculated with scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass.html Scipy also has a module for calculating distance between two points in an array: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist

Comment: Also note that Countours in OpenCV might be better tailored to your needs: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html

Comment: Thank you, Bobo. I will check it. Seem it could help.

Comment: Are you trying to use this as a shape descriptor for shape matching?

Comment: @dhanushka it is shape descriptor, bro. The image a will be convert to image b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did something like this a while back for fun, inspired by a Kaggle competition on [leaf classification](https://www.kaggle.com/c/leaf-classification). I used `opencv` for finding the contours of the images. Below is the code for python 2.7. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45323590/2571705) for the orientation of the returned contour. You may have to adapt it for your needs, specifically the thresholding part. Hope this helps.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def shape_desc(im):
    # threshold image
    _, bw = cv2.threshold(im, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    # find contours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    # extract largest contour
    largest_idx = np.argmax([len(contours[i]) for i in range(0, len(contours))])
    # get (x,y) coordinates
    x = np.array([contours[largest_idx][i][0][0] for i in range(0, len(contours[largest_idx]))], dtype = np.float).reshape((len(contours[largest_idx]), 1))
    y = np.array([contours[largest_idx][i][0][1] for i in range(0, len(contours[largest_idx]))], dtype = np.float).reshape((len(contours[largest_idx]), 1))
    # find the centroid
    m = cv2.moments(np.array([[x[i][0], y[i][0]] for i in range(0, len(x))]).reshape((-1, 1 ,2)).astype(np.int32))
    x_bar = m['m10']/m['m00']
    y_bar = m['m01']/m['m00']

    x_1 = np.array([i[0] for i in x])
    y_1 = np.array([i[0] for i in y])
    # take the centroid as the reference
    x = x_1 - x_bar
    y = y_1 - y_bar

    return np.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
```

Here are the results of applying this for the following images that are similar in shape. Note that the images and plots have been rescaled.

```
filename = '19.jpg'
im = cv2.imread(filename, 0)

desc = shape_desc(im)
plt.stem(desc)
```

[image: 16][image: 19]
[image: plot16][image: plot19]

Comment: Thank you. I will check it.